# IRS form 8960 (Net Investment Income Tax) Line 5a

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

Line 5a of Form 8960 says:

[image]

but when one looks at the instructions, it says:

[image]

further line 7 of form 1040 is this:

[image]

and this will include capital gain not just from **disposition of property** but also from **sale of stocks and bonds**. So there is a contradiction here. *The Form 8960 is saying to list the net gain (or loss) from disposition of property but the instructions are including the gains from sale of stocks and bonds as well.*

Who is right here and what exactly does one have to list in line 5a of Form 8960?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stocks and bonds that you own are your property, so you selling stocks and bonds is the disposition of your property. The instructions are consistent.